# "Error Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time"

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a ASP .NET Core Web API using  VS 2019 preview and .NET Core 3.0.
When I try execute : add-migration, I'm getting the error :
*"Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time,..."*

Below is my context file:

```
  public class AppDbContext : DbContext
  {
     public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { }
     public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
  }
```

My ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

  services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

My appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;DataBase....."
  },
...
}
```

I always using this approach and it works.

I also tried create a empty constructor in context class and the I got this error : 
*"System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext..."*

Am I forgetting some detail ?

note: This works fine in ASP .NET Core 2.2

Comment: make sure you have updated the Nuget packages. If not then > Right click on your project in solution explorer and select Manage Nuget packages and update the ones that have a little blue arrow. Hope, It will work for you!

Comment: Same problem, .NET Core 3.1 in VS 2019.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the migration how to create your `DbContext` by implementing the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>` interface: If a class implementing this interface is found in either the same project as the derived `DbContext` or in the application's startup project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the `DbContext` and use the design-time factory instead.

for more information see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class AppDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
    {
        public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql("Server=localhost;DataBase.....");

            return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```